# how to uninstall Internet explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I want to uninstall internet explorer from my windows 7 pc. Is it possible delete IE from pc. it is complete useless.

I tried uninstaling it from control panel but couldn't find an option.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Control Panel" -> "Uninstall programs" -> "Turn Windows features on or off" (on the left panel). Then uncheck "Internet Explorer" and press OK.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on Stackoverflow itself:

1. Go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and features
2. Go to Windows Features and disable Internet Explorer 11
3. Then click on Display installed updates
4. Then click on Display installed updates
5. Right-click on Internet Explorer 11 > Uninstall
6. Restart > Done.